# How to make my WebApp available offline?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

If you are using Google Calendar, you may noticed that they have ["Offline" feature](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/1340696?hl=en). You can use Google Calendar even if you are offline. I am interested to know what is the strategy that they are using to enable this feature?

I have a PHP/MySql invoicing application, and **I want to allow users to use my system even if they are offline**, then when internet is back, **data should be synced with the online version**.

I don't want to install my codes in my client's PCs, so I hope if someone has an idea that allows me to do same as what they did in Google Calendar or any other idea that may help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Javascript variable called localStorage. You can store there a queue of commands to the executed and you can can implement a synchronize function, like this:

```
function synchronize(queue) {
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        queue.pop().execute();
    }
}
```

You can use anything else, including Offline Storage, but remember that Offline Storage is supported only by HTML5, so if you want to support older browsers, then you need to have a fallback logic for those as well.